# Error parsing SQL Query in JSON

Tags: json

I'm using a JSON file to store some SQL queries as key value pairs but am getting parse errors which i think is being caused by some of the SQL Query characters.

If i remove the SQL query and enter plain text it parses fine so its definitely some SQL character thats causing the parse error.

Small snippet below

```
 {
  "SqlPart1": {
    "SqlRead": "
   SELECT
   Date,
   ID
   FROM DB.dbo.TableName
   WHERE SendEmail = 'true'
    ",
    "SqlWrite": "SqlQuery"
  },

  "SqlPart2": {
    "SqlRead": "SqlQuery",
    "SqlWrite": "SqlQuery"
  }
}
```

**Error**: `Parse error on line 3: ...": { "SqlRead": " SELECT Date, ----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'`

any idea's whats causing the issue?
I tried escaping the single quotes in the `WHERE` clause but made no difference.

thanks

Comment: I not sure at all, but i think you can't add multiline string this way in JSON. try to use \n instead of real new line in plain text: `"SqlRead": "\nSELECT\n Date,\n ID\n FROM DB.dbo.TableName\n WHERE SendEmail = 'true'\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to keep the formatting say for example in a big sql query, you can split

```
 {
  "SqlPart1": {
    "SqlRead": ["SELECT",
   "Date,",
   "ID",
   "FROM DB.dbo.TableName",
   "WHERE SendEmail = 'true'"]
    ",
    "SqlWrite": "SqlQuery"
  },
```

then join the array into a single string in your code. Not ideal but it's a limitation of json\javascript.

Answer (score 2):

JSON doesn't support multi-line text data in this way. You have to do it this way:

```
 {
  "SqlPart1": {
    "SqlRead": "\n   SELECT\n   Date, ...."
 ...
```

I.e. there must be no line breaks in string literals.